# Shut down a system by sending an sms from my phone

Tags: vbscript, sms, system-shutdown

I am currently working on a project where **I need to shut down my PC by sending an SMS from my phone**.

My idea is:

I have a my cellphone/USB modem with simcard connected to my laptop. So can I shutdown my laptop by sending a message "shutdown"? Here I need to have a program that reads what all sms coming to my phone which is connected to laptop. If the content of the message is "shutdown", then I can call a batch file where my shutdown command is written.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but much easier using a SMS service like Esendex (www.esendex.com there are loads of others).

You can host a webservice on the machine (or another on the same network).  The webservice recieves the SMS and process it depending on the message it contaions. When you send an SMS to your Esendex account this webservice is called and if the message reads Shutdown (or whatever keyword you choose to look for) you can simply call the shutdown batch file.

if you want to do it without using something like esendex you will need to write some code that monitors the SMS's coming into the attached phone.  How you do this will depend on the type of phone you have connected I believe.

Comment: @Fredthanks for the quick response...**can u suggest any code that monitors the SMS's coming into my android phone or USB modem with SIM connected to pc?**

Comment: I suspect you will need to write some code to do this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231247/how-to-send-and-read-sms-from-mobile-attached-to-pc this SO article may help.  This library may also help http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/23/how-to-receive-sms-using-net-sms-library/